# How to attach local files to Drupal nodes

Tags: drupal, file-upload, drupal-6

I need to attach video files to nodes in Drupal 6, yet the AJAX uploader fails (the dreaded HTTP error 0), and anything I tried to debug it didn't help (may be moving to Drupal 7 will, but that's still going to be some time). Is it possible to somehow upload the file to the server via FTP, and then simply attach it to a node, so that it is linked in the same way that it would be linked after a regular file attachment?

This is **not** about CCK's FileField. This is about the "vanilla" node attachments. To do the same for FileField uploads I used FileField Sources module, and I'd like to find a similar solution for the node attachments.

Comment: I haven't used it in a while but IMCE http://drupal.org/project/imce might let you more easily manage files on the server - if you uploaded directly to drupal's sites/[sitename]/files directory especially.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - the list of IMCE features does not have this, and there is a request to add this possibility here: http://drupal.org/node/259919?mode=2&sort=2, but looks like it was never done (though the issue is marked as closed - it is not clear why, I'll need to look deeper). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a solution, I had to switch to using CCK FileField, and use FileField Sources module (http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) to upload files to the server and then attach them to the field.

Thanks for trying to help me, guys!

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in limit upload file size.

1. check it is in php.ini settings
2. do not forget that max package size limits upload size too
3. check drupal settings (drupal file system settings or filefield settings)

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help, even though I asked a different question. I did check 1 and 3 already, but can you please clarify 2 - is it another php parameter apart from upload_max_filesize and post_max_size?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had something like this problem when I configured a site to run over SSL but not all the URLs in the system were being properly adjusted or redirected. I set the $base_url variable in settings.php to use ***https***://www.example.com` and the error stopped.

In my case I believe it related to a Taxonomy tagging autocomplete callback, but all Ajax callbacks in the system can be sensitive on this point.

[#646694 AJAX: Terrible reporting of status 0 response from AJAX request ("HTTP Error 0 has occurred")](http://drupal.org/node/646694)

Comment: Yep, I've seen that thread, and I don't want to patch the core - that's why I am looking for a file attachment solution.

Comment: Oh, and I don't use https :( But thanks for offering to help anyway.

Comment: Not suggesting you patch core, suggesting that it is the primary place of discussion for your issue, cross-linked with other issues of people experiencing this. The vagueness of the error makes it very difficult to troubleshoot without seeing someone else complain of the same problem while doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. But if the most frequent solutions don't work, then one is lost in the dark without patching the core.